# How to override allowedTypes in PHP Codesniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I've managed to get PHP CodeSniffer installed and working. I have also managed to write my own custom sniffs.

There is one issue that I cannot figure out - how do I override the `$allowedTypes` variable which is defined in the main `PHP_CodeSniffer` class:

```
public static $allowedTypes = array(
   'array',
   'boolean',
   'float',
   'integer',
   'mixed',
   'object',
   'string',
   'resource',
   'callable',
);
```

I would like to add 'bool' and 'int' options to this array, but without monkey patching the core repository.

Comment: use the magic method `__set`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this issue: the topic was discussed at [github](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/260).

The variable cannot be overridden using command line arguments or the XML configuration file.

The easiest solution is to implement a custom Sniff making use of your own `suggestType` implementation.